# Validation rules of Opportunity triggered while adding Opportunity Products

Tags: validation, validation-rule

As per my understanding, field updates from workflow will NOT trigger any custom validation rules.

In my case it triggers custom validation rules on opportunity when I try to insert a new OpportunityProduct.

There are few workflow rules on OpportunityProduct that updates fields on Opportunity object.

Why is it doing so. How to avoid it ?

Comment: This is happening because Opportunity is the Master of the Line Items and when updates to the Line Items happen the rollups update (as well as amount and other fields) get updated on the opportunity thus firing validation rules. No real way around it. You will have to evaluate the requirements for your validation rules and work with this new knowledge

Comment: The field `Opportunity.hasProducts` will tell your VR rules on Opportunity if any products exist.